# Sticky content resets page when it's supposed to stick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a filterable content section that I would like to stick to the top when you scroll to it.

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|      HEADER      |
+------------------+ <--- WHEN THIS IS COVERED BY TOP OF BROWSER WINDOW (SCROLLED UP)
|                  | <--- THIS BECOMES FIXED TO TOP AND SCROLLABLE
|                  |
|      STICKY      |
|      CONTENT     |
+------------------+
```

As of right now, the header section will be nearly hidden from the scroll, then it will flash and reset the scroll to the top. Not really sure what could be doing it.

As for **HTML** the only `<div>` you should need to worry about is `#sticky` and `.whole-page-container` the two are synonymous, just called differently. `#sticky` is used in the `jQuery` function and `.whole-page-container` is used for the `CSS`.

**CSS:**

```
.whole-page-container{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
----------------------------

USED TO FIX THE CONTENT TO THE TOP (STICKY IT)
    .stuck {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var stickyNavTop = $('#sticky').offset().top;  

var stickyNav = function(){  
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
    $('#sticky').addClass('stuck');  
} else {  
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stuck');   
}  
};  

stickyNav();  

$(window).scroll(function() {  
    stickyNav();  
});  
});
```

Also here is a link to the working example: **[EXAMPLE](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3459601480&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=341117)**

Thanks for the help!

PICTORIAL EXAMPLE

So if this is the current page when you load
[image: Example 1]
The `#RED` section will be scrollable, as you scroll the page this will move with it.

Once you reach this point, where the `#BLUE` section is at the top, I would like this blue section to fix to the top so you can scroll through the content.
[image: Example 2]

Comment: **In reply to the two close votes**.. I'm not sure how it isn't clear what I'm trying to achieve. I have a content section that I want to be below the header section. When you scroll, the content section comes up and ill lock in place to the top. Think of a sticky-header, but this is more than a header. 

**In reply to the one saying this isn't a programming question:** What? This is clearly a JS/jQuery question.

Comment: You've got an awfully deep nesting level of divs there. As far as I can see, the whole page is contained inside the sticky div.

Comment: @Mr Lister The whole page *should* be in the sticky div, except the Header/nav/footer, and the small blue section that says "About".

Comment: OK, so then the whole page should be fixed, with a top value of 0?

Comment: The whole page **underneath** the header/nav and "About" section. Excluding the footer on the bottom. I can make an image to kind of explain it if you'd like.

Comment: Are you sure that working example is working?

Comment: Is it not for you? I didn't mean working, I meant here is my example I am working on. When you scroll down and get to the point the content is supposed to stick, it resets the scroll.

Comment: you should start with correcting your js errors:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function(anonymous function) @ AND Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: The magnificPopup isn't on this page, but the file is loaded throughout the whole site. That shouldn't apply to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I incased my current `.whole-page-container` in another `<div>`. Gave the outer most `div` the class `.whole-page-container` and gave the second outer most `div` (prviously `.whole-page-container` the div of `sticky`.

Removed `position:fixed` and replaced with `position:static`.